# NameError: name 'MNIST' is not defined

Tags: python, import, mnist

I got the following error when I tried to import mnist:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
import mnist

data_path = "../dataset"
mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original', data_home=data_path)

#mnist = MNIST('../dataset/MNIST')
x_train, y_train = mnist.load_training() #60000 samples
x_test, y_test = mnist.load_testing()    #10000 samples
X_train = np.asarray(x_train).astype(np.float32)
y_train = np.asarray(y_train).astype(np.int32)
X_test = np.asarray(x_test).astype(np.float32)
y_test = np.asarray(y_test).astype(np.int32)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-5cbf011c3576> in <module>
      1 import mnist
      2 
----> 3 mnist = MNIST('../dataset/MNIST')
      4 x_train, y_train = mnist.load_training() #60000 samples
      5 x_test, y_test = mnist.load_testing()    #10000 samples

NameError: name 'MNIST' is not defined
```

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-5e6e64b70463> in <module>
----> 1 from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
      2 import mnist
      3 
      4 data_path = "../dataset"
      5 mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original', data_home=data_path)

ImportError: cannot import name 'fetch_mldata' from 'sklearn.datasets' (C:\Users\Angelus\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\__init__.py)
```

I used Anaconda to install mist. I tried to uninstall it and install it again but I still receive the same error message

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how you use Python, import and mnist, your syntax is wrong. From the documentation:

```
from mnist import MNIST
mndata = MNIST('./dir_with_mnist_data_files')
```

And please don't use `mnist` as a variable name because it's a package name. Already.

Comment: I think there is a problem with importing mnist but I don't know how to fix it? "ImportError: cannot import name 'MNIST' from 'mnist' (C:\Users\Angelus\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mnist\__init__.py)"

Comment: This is simple. You’re using package called “mnist”. Effectively doesn’t have MNIST defined. You may have needed to install “python-mnist” instead(which does have MNIST). They are often confused. Read on the internet to understand which one you need.